# 90amp breaker to a subpanel for 60 amps

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a mobile home that is wired for a 90 amp furnace. but didn't have the furnace.. so I purchased one which is  60 amps.
could I take the wires for the 90 amp furnace run it from the 90 amp breaker into the main lug in a subpanel and use a 60 amp breaker for this other furnace?

Comment: Why not just change the breaker to a 60 amp?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply continue to use the 90 amp wires.  You change the breaker to 60A, they're about $10, but hold on to the old 90A breaker because those critters are expensive.

This depends on the rule that you are always allowed to use larger wires than required.